# JQuery mobile - how to add current URL to browser history

Tags: jquery-mobile, anchor, browser-history

Normal links like:

```html
 <a href="#anchor">My Link</a>
```

don't work in JQuery mobile because JQm uses "#" to navigate between pages.
Therefore I dynamically generate links to anchors like this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('a.native-anchor').bind('click', function(ev) {
         var target = $( $(this).attr('href') ).get(0).offsetTop;
         $.mobile.silentScroll(target);
         return false;
     });
</script>
```

This works, but when I use the browser back-button I'not going back to the link where I came from but to the previous page. This is because my onclick function does not add the current page to the browser history.

Does JQuery mobile have a way to add the current page (and anchor) to the browser history?

I tried

```js
 $.mobile.urlHistory.addNew(window.location.pathname);
```

but this is not working (probably because I'm not sure which arguments to pass to addNew).